# Clarifying correct usage for <meta name="format-detection">

Tags: html, format, meta-tags, detection, specifications

I cannot find a standard *W3* or *WHAT-WG* (or even non-standard third-party) **spec** for:

```
<meta name="format-detection">
```

I have two principle questions.

**Question 1: What *formats* may be referenced in the `format-detection` meta-tag?**

Most commonly, third-party references cite `telephone`.

Occasionally `email` or `date` are cited.

More rarely, `address` is cited.

One source (https://www.goodemailcode.com/email-code/template.html) cites `url`.

This gives the following list of formats:

- `telephone`
- `email`
- `date`
- `address`
- `url`

Is that the complete list of formats? Are there any others?

**Question 2: Must each format be individually referenced, or can any number of formats be referenced together in a single meta-tag?**

That is to ask, is it necessary to declare:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="email=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">
<meta name="format-detection" content="url=no">
```

Or is this perfectly acceptable:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, email=no, date=no, address=no, url=no">
```

If `format-detection` isn't an accepted standard, I'm entirely happy to refer to a non-standard spec (or blog post), so long as the document has some authority and isn't simply a third-party observation or comment.